# update statement with case statement data type conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case-statement

I am trying to write a `UPDATE` statement which includes `CASE` statement
the datatype of SCIENCE_TH is nvarchar(2) and SCIENCE_TTL is nvarchar(3).

```
update STUDENT_MARKS_TEMP 
set     
SCIENCE_TH  = CASE WHEN (SCIENCE_TTL  <> 'Ab' AND try_convert(NUMERIC(38, 2), SCIENCE_TTL )  < 30.00 ) THEN (30.00 - try_convert(NUMERIC(38, 2), SCIENCE_TTL ) ) else  SCIENCE_TH   end
// remaining block ...
```

what I am trying to do is when `case` statement condition is false the value of `SCIENCE_TH` should be  updated as `SCIENCE_TH`. But I am getting error as ::

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: Show us the data...

Comment: When I am trying to build a statement like that I always start with a select query until I have tested that the values being generated for the update are correct. You can then break down the calculation into smaller chunks to determine where issues are.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to update 'xx.xx' to varchar(2) (because output of arithmatic operation on two numerics will be a numeric, not an int), which is not possible. So, I have taken the left 2, which you can change based on the data whether the right 2 or left 2 whichever you want. Ideally you should increase the size if data demands that.

```
SCIENCE_TH  = 
CASE
WHEN 
(SCIENCE_TTL  <> 'Ab'
 AND try_convert(NUMERIC(38, 2), SCIENCE_TTL )  < 
 30.00) THEN 
 LEFT(CAST((30.00 - try_convert(NUMERIC(38, 2), 
SCIENCE_TTL ) ) AS  VARCHAR),2)
else  
SCIENCE_TH   
 end
 // remaining block ..
```

Comment: I don't think that is the case with CAST and VARCHAR together. I tried to simulate to clarify your suggestion here: https://rextester.com/FEKA94560. Please take a look and correct me if I am wrong :).

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** The datatype for `SCIENCE_TH` is nvarchar(2) and `SCIENCE_TTL` is nvarchar(3).The error message indicates that there is an *overflow* when converting the expression  to data type `nvarchar`(here it may be a `numeric` value of length 3 as base column `SCIENCE_TTL` has length 3).

**Reproduce the Issue:**

```
declare @T Table (SCIENCE_TH nvarchar(2), SCIENCE_TTL nvarchar(3))

insert into @T (SCIENCE_TTL) values ('1.1')

update @T
set SCIENCE_TH =  (30.00 - try_convert(NUMERIC(38, 2), SCIENCE_TTL ) )
```

**Solution:** Make sure that the length of the NVARCHAR variable or column is long enough to hold the numeric value, counting the decimal point as part of the converted NVARCHAR value.

Alter `SCIENCE_TH` to a minimum nvarchar(5) to resolve above error.